# Структура "Pair": реализовать метод root(), вычисляющий корень линейного уравнения

Tags: c

Линейное ура-ние y=Ax+B.Поле first дробное число коэффициент А;Поле second-дробное число,коэффициент В.Реализовать метод root()-вычисление корня линейного ура-ния. Метод должен проверять неравенство коэффициента В к нулю.Написал код для обчисления,если А и B просто целые числа.Помогите организовать структуру,которая будет вводить два числителя и два знаменателя а потом делить эти дроби.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct tdrib
{
    float first;
    float second;
};


 int check(struct tdrib *pob){
    if(pob->first == 0){
        printf("No answer\n");
        return 1;
     }
     else return 0;
 }
 void input(struct tdrib *pob)

        {
    do
    {
    printf("\nInput A->");
    scanf("%d",&pob->first);
    printf("\nInput B->");
    scanf("%d",&pob->second);
    }
    while(check(pob)==1);
}

 float root(struct tdrib *pob)
    {
        return(-pob->second/pob->first);
    }
 output(struct tdrib* ob1){
    printf(" rezult=%f\n",root(ob1));
    }


int main()
{
    struct tdrib ob1,ob2;
    input(&ob1);
    input(&ob2);
    output(&ob1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Непонятен вопрос. Вы же вроде все более-менее написали, только и того, что `%d` надо на `%f` заменить да `void` перед `output` написать... В чем проблема-то?

Comment: я ввожу а и b как целые числа,а они должны быть дробью с числителем и знаменателем.То есть,я должен вводить два числителя и два знаменателя а потом разделить эти дроби.Не знаю,как сделать еще одну подструктуру к структуре tdrib

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вам нужна структура с **четырьмя** полями - два числителя и два знаменателя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct tdrib
{
    int an, // numerator - числитель
        ad; // denominator - знаменатель
    int bn, bd;

    int rn, rd;  // результат
};

int gcd(int m, int n)
{
    while(m && n) if (m < n) n %= m; else m %= n;
    return m + n;
}


int check(struct tdrib *pob)
{
    if(pob->ad == 0 || pob->bd == 0 || pob-> an == 0)
    {
        printf("No answer\n");
        return 1;
     }
     else return 0;
}

void input(struct tdrib *pob)
{
    do
    {
        printf("\nInput A as an/ad ->");
        scanf("%d/%d",&pob->an,&pob->ad);
        printf("\nInput B as bn/bd ->");
        scanf("%d/%d",&pob->bn,&pob->bd);
        if (pob->ad < 0) { pob->ad = -pob->ad; pob->an = -pob->an; }
        if (pob->bd < 0) { pob->bd = -pob->bd; pob->bn = -pob->bn; }
    }
    while(check(pob) == 1);
}

void root(struct tdrib *pob)
{
    pob->rn = -pob->bn*pob->ad;
    pob->rd =  pob->bd*pob->an;
    if (pob->rd < 0) { pob->rd = -pob->rd; pob->rn = -pob->rn; }
    int g = gcd(abs(pob->rn),pob->rd);
    pob->rn /= g;
    pob->rd /= g;

}

void output(struct tdrib* ob)
{
    root(ob);
    printf(" result=%d/%d\n",ob->rn,ob->rd);
}

int main()
{
    struct tdrib ob;
    input(&ob);
    output(&ob);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Еще вопрос,а что делает функция qcd?

Comment: Вычисляет [GCD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C) :)

Comment: bn и bd это что?

Comment: А хоть немного поработать самостоятельно?...